# Summing columns with same names in the row and show it in new sheet run with date

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel worksheet Cell F5, F7, F8 has a name of XXX and F6,F9,F10 has name of YYY and hours for those names is mentioned in Column  K. There are two types of hours and that will be mentioned in Column H.

Each row will be entered on different dates and dates will be on Column A.

What I need is, if I enter from date and to date on Command box it must sum up the hours on that particular name with type of hours worked within those dates and show it in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIFS formula:

Formula for B5 in Sheet2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$H:$H,Sheet1!$A:$A,">="&Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A,"<="&Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet2!A5)
```

Formula for B6 in Sheet2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$H:$H,Sheet1!$A:$A,">="&Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A,"<="&Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet2!A6)
```

Formula for C5 in Sheet2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$K:$K,Sheet1!$A:$A,">="&Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A,"<="&Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet2!A5)
```

Formula for C6 in Sheet2:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$K:$K,Sheet1!$A:$A,">="&Sheet2!$B$1,Sheet1!$A:$A,"<="&Sheet2!$B$2,Sheet1!$F:$F,Sheet2!A6)
```

## Sheet1:

[image]

## Sheet2:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Adnan,,

Comment: @Balachandar Accept this answer if your problem is resolved